Discontinuity as the difference of Feynman integral on the second sheet and that on the physical sheet
In What is the i$\epsilon$ for the S-matrix sec 3.7, they discuss about the evaluation of discontinuity of Feynman integral,
$$\text{disc}_{s=(m1+m2)^2}\mathcal{I}_{\text{bub}} = \frac{1}{2i}\Gamma(2-D/2)\int_{\gamma}\frac{d\alpha}{(-\tilde{\mathcal{V}})^{2-D/2}}\tag{3.61}$$
where $\gamma$ is the figure-eight contour created by the difference of deformed contour and the original contour.
They interpret the discontinuity as quoted,

Here, the symbol “disc” on the left-hand side denotes
the difference between the value of $\mathcal{I}_{\text{bub}}$ after analytically continuing anti-clockwise around the normal threshold once (without crossing any branch cuts) and the original
value of $\mathcal{I}_{\text{bub}}$ divided by $2i$.

By without crossing any branch cuts, they mean the branch cuts on the real $s$ axis. However, then they claim it is also the difference of Feynman integral on the second sheet and that on the physical sheet.

In other words, we should think about a discontinuity as
the difference between the value of the Feynman integral on the second sheet of the corresponding threshold cut and that on the physical sheet.

My question is: since they perform the deformation of the integral contour such that ss does not cross any branch cuts, how can a Feynman integral on the second sheet be present in this context?
I believe that a Feynman integral on the second sheet can only appear when certain variables cross the branch cuts and enter the second sheet. Am I mistaken in this understanding?
